# How to return a formatted string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, string-formatting

Assume you're coding in golang, you can do something like:

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("%d is bigger than %d", 6, 4)
```

How about Erlang?

Comment: <https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1>, and I'm sure it took me less time to google than you have spent typing your question.

Comment: @kostix that doesn't answer my question

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question, being easy to Google doesn't mean that it shouldn't be on SO

Comment: @radrow, SO was invented for solving non-trivial problems. Reading manuals is a trivial one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Erlang equivalent would be

```
Str = io_lib:format("~p is bigger than ~p", [6, 4])
```

Note that, even if the result may be not technically a string, normally there is no need to convert it to the string by calling `lists:flatten`. The result of the format function usually is a special case of *iolist*. Virtually all Erlang functions expecting a string accept iolists as arguments as well.

"Usually" above means "if Unicode modifier is not used in the format string". In most cases there is no need to use Unicode modifiers, and the result of `format` can be used directly as described above.

Comment: "The result of the format function is a special case of iolist." --  I'm not sure what you mean by a "special case of an iolist", because a term is either an iolist or it's not an iolist.  Maybe you meant "subset of an iolist"?  But then that's just incorrect.  The fact is `io_lib:format/2` may return an iolist, or it may return something that is not an iolist.  In any case, this is probably a much more technical discussion than the op wanted or can understand.  Suffice it to say, the op may get something that can be treated as a string or they may not.

Comment: @7stud I added a paragraph about this nuance, I hope now the answer is technically correct.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you wrote.  An iolist() requires integers less than 255, i.e. a byte() type, while utf-8 characters can have codepoints higher than 255.  Yet you seem to be saying that if a list contains a codepoint that is a utf-8 character, then it is an iolist().

Comment: @7stud This is not what I was saying at all. What I am saying is that the result of format function may include numbers bigger than 255 only if Unicode modifiers are present in the format string. This is what the official documentation is saying and it means that if you don’t use Unicode modifiers, the result of format is an iolist.

Comment: Then you agree that this statement is incorrect: "These modifiers are part of Erlang support for Unicode encodings other than the default UTF-8." and that the modifiers are also needed for UTF-8 characters with codepoints greater than 255?

Comment: @7stud Thank you for pointing this, I removed the incorrect sentence.

Answer (score 2):

There is `io_lib:format/2`, that does the job, but note that it returns a possibly nested list of chars, not a string. For a proper string, you have to `flatten/1` it afterwards:

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p is bigger than ~p", [6, 4]))
```

Comment: Where do the docs say that `io_lib:format/2` returns an io_list()?  The docs I'm looking at say that `io_lib:format/2` returns a string (which in erlang is a list of integers).

Comment: At least on my machine `io_lib:format("test ~p", [1]).` returns `[116,101,115,116,32,"1"]` which is clearly not a string (but a nested list of ints).

Comment: But you are right, it's not an iolist, but `[char() | chars()]`

Comment: I was mistaken: `io_lib:format/2` does not return a string, rather it returns a nested list of integers. A string() is defined as a flat list of integers, e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`, whereas `io_lib:format/2` returns something like `[1, 2, [3]]`, which is an iolist if the first two integers are less than 255.  Pretty confusing.

Answer (score -1):

To use `io_lib:format/2` with unicode characters:

```
50> X = io_lib:format("~s is greater than ~s", [[8364], [36]]). 
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  io_lib:format/2
        called as io_lib:format("~s is greater than ~s",[[8364],"$"])

51> X = io_lib:format("~ts is greater than ~s", [[8364], [36]]).
[[8364],
 32,105,115,32,103,114,101,97,116,101,114,32,116,104,97,110,
 32,"$"]

52> io:format("~s~n", [X]).                                     
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  io:format/2
        called as io:format("~s~n",
                            [[[8364],
                              32,105,115,32,103,114,101,97,116,101,114,32,116,
                              104,97,110,32,"$"]])
        *** argument 1: failed to format string

53> io:format("~ts~n", [X]).
€ is greater than $
ok
```